# Magento 2 customer attribute not working in Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2, customer-account, customer-attribute, eav-attributes

I have created a module for adding a customer attribute and show it in create account form on frontend and account edit in backend, the thing is that it worked in Magento 2.2 but not on Magento 2.3.3, I don't know if it changes.

Here is my code.

InstallData.php

```
<?php
namespace Kage\RegisterForm\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerMetadataInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
{
    /**
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\Config
     */
    private $eavConfig;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Installs data for a module
     *
     * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
     * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
     * @return void
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $setup->startSetup();

        $attributeCode = 'register_zip_code';
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, 'register_zip_code', [
            'type' => 'text',
            'label' => 'Zip Code',
            'input' => 'text',
            'required' => true,
            'visible' => true,
            'source' => '',
            'backend' => '',
            'user_defined' => true,
            'is_user_defined' => false,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'is_used_in_grid' => false,
            'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
            'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
            'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
            'position' => 1000,
            'default' => 0,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $eavSetup->addAttributeToSet(
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER,
            CustomerMetadataInterface::ATTRIBUTE_SET_ID_CUSTOMER,
            null,
            $attributeCode);

        $registerZipCode= $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(CustomerMetadataInterface::ENTITY_TYPE_CUSTOMER, $attributeCode);
        $registerZipCode->setData('used_in_forms', [
            'adminhtml_customer',
            'customer_account_create',
            'customer_account_edit'
        ]);
        $registerZipCode->getResource()->save($registerZipCode);

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

view/frontend/layout/customer_account_create.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="register_zip_code" template="Kage_RegisterForm::register.phtml"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

view/templates/register.phtml

```
<fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
    <p>
    <div class="field required regulation">
        <label for="regulation" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
                echo __('Zip Code') ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input type="text" name="register_zip_code" id="register_zip_code" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Zip Code') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
        </div>
    </div>
    </p>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same requirement for the barcode in magento 2.3.3 and its working.

Here is the code.

Module Name : Multiunique_Stackoverflow.

1. Create an InstallData.php at app/code/Multiunique/Stackoverflow/Setup/ and add below code.

   ```
   <?php
   namespace Multiunique\Stackoverflow\Setup;


   use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;

   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
   use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

   use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
   use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
   use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
   use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
   use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetup;


   class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface 
   {
    /**
    * @var CustomerSetupFactory
    */
   protected $customerSetupFactory;

   /**
    * @var AttributeSetFactory
    */
   private $attributeSetFactory;

   /**
    * InstallData constructor.
    *
    * @param CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
    * @param AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    */
   public function __construct(
       CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
       AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
   ) {
       $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
       $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
   }


   /**
    * Install
    *
    * @param ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup
    * @param ModuleContextInterface $context
    * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
    * @throws \Zend_Validate_Exception
    * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.UnusedFormalParameter)
    */
   public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
   {
       /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
       $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

       $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
       $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

       /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
       $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
       $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

       $customerSetup->addAttribute(
           Customer::ENTITY,
           'barcode',
           [
               'type' => 'varchar',
               'label' => 'Barcode Customer',
               'input' => 'text',
               'required' => false,
               'visible' => true,
               'user_defined' => true,
               'position' => 999,
               'system' => 0,
               'is_used_in_grid' => 1,
               'is_visible_in_grid' => 1,
               'is_filterable_in_grid' => 1,
               'is_searchable_in_grid' => 1
           ]
       );

       $attribute = $customerSetup
           ->getEavConfig()
           ->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'barcode')
           ->addData(
               [
                   'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                   'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                   'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer', 'customer_account_edit','customer_account_create']
               ]
           );
       $attribute->save();
   }
   ```

   }
2. Create customer_account_create.xml at app/code/Multiunique/Stackoverflow/view/frontend/layout    and add below code

   ```
   <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>    
   <referenceContainer name="form.additional.info">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customer_barcode" template="Multiunique_Stackoverflow::register.phtml"/>
       </referenceContainer>
   </body>
   </page>
   ```
3. add register.hml at app/code/Multiunique/Stackoverflow/view/frontend/templates and add below code

   ```
   <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
     <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Additional Information') ?></span></legend>
   <p>
   <div class="field required barcode">
       <label for="barcode" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */
               echo __('Barcode') ?></span></label>
       <div class="control">
           <input type="text" name="barcode" id="barcode" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Barcode') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}">
       </div>
   </div>
   </p>
   </fieldset>
   ```

let me know if it helps else i will share my custom module.

Thanks
Amit

Comment: Hi! I copied the InstallData.php but did not work either :( it's not creating the attribute in database, what could it be?

Comment: This code we use mostly in all our projects and it works. I think you should check why attribute is not created. may be create new module with different namespace. or upgrade your module and use upgradedata script.

Comment: Attribute should be created on eav_attribute table right?

Comment: Yes eav_attribute table stores all attributes with their entiry_type. for customer the enetity _type_id is 1